# Jest is not able to import ts/tsx modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gruntjs, jestjs, ts-jest

When I try to import typescript modules into my unit tests I get an error stating `Unable to resolve path to module 'src/js/TestNum'`. It does not have the same issue doing identical imports from js/jsx files.

In the past when I have had issues importing typescript modules it complained about an unexpected token syntax error.

**TestNum.ts**

```
export const TestNum1 = 5;
export const TestNum2 = 10;
```

**TestStr.js**

```
export const TestStr1 = '5';
export const TestStr2 = '10';
```

**test.js**

```
/* global describe test */
import expect from 'expect';
import { TestNum1 } from 'src/js/TestNum';
import { TestStr1 } from 'src/js/TestStr';

describe('example', () => {
  test('if constant is 5', () => {
    expect(TestNum1).toEqual(5);
  });
  test('if constant is "5"', () => {
    expect(TestStr1).toEqual(5);
  });
});
```

In vscode, if I click on the import that is failing and push F2, It will navigate to the definition of the import.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-graphql-tag": "1.6.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.1",
    "expect": "^24.8.0",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-exec": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "jest-config": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^2.5.0",
    "load-grunt-config": "^1.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2",
    "ts-jest": "23.10.5",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "start-dev-shell",
    "stop": "stop-dev-shell",
    "restart": "restart-dev-shell"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
const { defaults } = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {
  coverageDirectory: 'build/test-results/code-coverage-reports',
  moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js'
  },
  'reporters': ['default', ['./node_modules/jest-html-reporter', { 'pageTitle': 'Test Report' }]],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/build-utils/',
    '<rootDir>/dist/',
    '<rootDir>/build/',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/'
  ],
  testRegex: 'test/unit/.+Tests?\\.(js|ts|jsx|tsx)?', //updated to grab ts/tsx tests
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>']
};
```

**Edit**

One new thing I found after playing around based on the comments was that if I switch my test to be a typescript test then it will not be able to find my module if referenced from `src` instead of a relative path `../../src`. This will also prevent the IDE from jumping to the definition.

Comment: try making path relative: `./src/js/TestNum`. I think in current form bundler tries to find node module with name `src` and fails

Comment: Why are you not writing your tests in Typescript?

Comment: We are migrating to ts from an existing js repo. This scenario needs to work if I'm going to get any confidence in this migration.

Comment: @skyboyer switching to a relative path does not change the error. The IDE is still able to jump to the definition so the path should work.